# Is it possible to extract frames from a live camera feed in react-native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, webrtc

I am trying to send image frames to a tensor flow library on a server. I got it all setup using pure React JS, but implementing it on react-native is giving me a lot of problems.

It seems impossible to get the frames from the webRCT stream, and even without the webRCT I can't find a way to even get frames from any video in react-native.

Has anyone found a good solution to this?

Comment: Did you manage to get it to work?

Comment: No and we are moving to open CV and native code to get this to work

Comment: thanks! Anyway, I have done the same via bridging in both platforms.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a library that can do this for you? Maybe this one can help:

https://github.com/react-native-webrtc/react-native-webrtc

Instead of "pure" ReactJS you need a bit of configuration for both Android & iOS after installing the module.

Comment: Yea that's what I am using, I am looking for a way to extract the individual frames from the stream, and send the images to the server.